# Replace text which contains some element from first list (patterns) and replace it by elements in other list (replacements) in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Hello I have this table

```
WITH datos as (WITH ['This not change','this text is the second word','this is a exact mach','and this not change'] as datosSup
select arrayJoin(datosSup) as Title)
select * from datos
```

### My Table

| Title |
| --- |
| first word |
| this text is the second word |
| this is a exact mach |
| and this not change |

**And two lists,**

```
['is the second word','this is a exact mach'] as patterns,
['contains second word','replaced text exact match'] as replacements
```

I have been able to replace text if "*Title*" field exact match with one element of list patterns

```
WITH datos as (WITH ['first word','this text is the second word','this is a exact mach','and this not change'] as datosSup
select arrayJoin(datosSup) as Title),
['is the second word','this is a exact mach'] as pattern,
['contains second word','replaced text exact match'] as replacement
select if(indexOf(pattern,Title)>0,replacement[indexOf(pattern,Title)],Title)  from  datos
```

### Result:

| Title |
| --- |
| first word |
| this text is the second word |
| **replaced text exact match** |
| and this not change |

But I want replace text which **contains** some element from first list (patterns) and replace it by elements in other list (replacements).

## Result desired:

| Title |
| --- |
| first word |
| **this text contains second word** |
| **replaced text exact match** |
| and this not change |

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone, I was answered in another forum as follows

```
SELECT arrayJoin(if(length(replaced) = 0, [Title], replaced)) AS replaced_title
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Title,
        groupArray(my_replace(Title, pattern, replacement)) AS replaced
    FROM t, p
    GROUP BY Title
)
```

Table p is (pattern String, replacement String).  Unfortunately ClickHouse's REPLACE() takes constant only for pattern and replacement.  So I made a function my_replace

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_replace AS
    (haystack,pattern,replacement) -> 
    if(position(haystack,pattern)== 0, NULL,substring(haystack, 1, position(haystack, pattern)-1) ||
                 replacement || 
                 substring(haystack, position(haystack, pattern) + length(pattern),
                 length(haystack) - position(haystack, pattern) - length(pattern) + 1))
```

### Result

| Title |
| --- |
| first word |
| replaced text exact match |
| and this not change |
| this text contains second word |